# JSONP with Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey

I'm trying to get JSON from object, but I'm getting exception:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class Controllers.MyJax, genericType=class Controllers.MyJax.
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. 
My code is similar to code from [official documentatin.](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e7143)

I filled up all three conditions:

> 1. Resource method, which should return wrapped JSON, needs to be annotated with @JSONP annotation.
> 2. MessageBodyWriter for application/json media type, which also accepts the return type of the resource method, needs to be registered
>      (see JSON section of this chapter). 
>      **(by annotation @Produces)**
> 3. User's request has to contain Accept header with one of the JavaScript media types defined (see below).

I have tried like this:

```
@Produces("application/json")
```

and

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

My code:

```
@GET
@Path("new")
@JSONP
@Produces("application/json")
public MyJax ewUser() {

    return new MyJax("jsonp");

}
```

and:

```
package Controllers;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class MyJax {

    private String value;

    public MyJax() {}

    public MyJax(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Just add this to pom.xml

[depency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.3.3)